# does VB6 allow referencing Form instance as a singleton just by naming its data type? or what is happening?

Tags: oop, vb6

I am seeing code like "Unload frmMain" where from what I can tell frmMain is the type/module name, and I don't think it could also be simultaneously a variable name of the "ObjFrmMain" sort. Nevertheless, this command does successfully induce the form in question to unload.

So is the data type being used as an alias for its single existing instance? Or maybe for all of its instances?

Does VB6 do similar things to data types other than those derived from Form?

Comment: Only for forms for each class you have an implicit global `Dim frmMain As New frmMain`. This is left for compatibility with MS Access style of coding where you can use `SELECT ... WHERE Field LIKE frmMain!TextBox.Text` kind of queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, VB6 has odd object behavior.  It gives you some shortcuts for dealing with form objects.

```
Load frmMain
```

...will load a single instance of that form under that variable name.  In fact:

```
frmMain.lblSomeLabel.Caption = "some caption"
```

... will load that instance.  However:

```
frmMain.SomeStringMember = "some value"
```

... will not *load* the form object (meaning the window itself) but you can access these variables, so in essence, the name of the form is a global variable.

You can, however, create new instances:

```
Dim newForm As MyForm
Set newForm = New MyForm
newForm.Show vbModal
```

That will actually create a new instance of `MyForm`, load it and show it, so you can have multiple instances of one form.

Also beware of the oddness in the `New` keyword:

```
Dim newObject As New MyClass
Set newObject = Nothing
newObject.SomeStringProperty = "some value"
```

This works without an "Object Reference Not Set ..." error.  When you declare a reference variable using the `As New` syntax, you can destroy the object by setting it to `Nothing` and then reference that variable again and it will *create a new instance*.

In fact that's what's really going on with the forms.  There is an implicit:

```
Dim frmMain As New frmMain
```

Personally I prefer not to use the `As New` syntax because it's confusing and dangerous.  It also has a performance penalty, vs. this:

```
Dim newObject As MyClass
Set newObject = New MyClass
```

... but you're stuck with it for the forms.

What's happening when you call `Unload frmMain` is that it unloads the window (and all the controls) so all the data in those are gone, but the object `frmMain` is still hanging around.  Therefore even after you unload it, you can still access any member variables and properties.  However, if anything references any control on the form, it will trigger an implicit `Load frmMain`.  This is the source of a lot of subtle programming errors in VB6, especially when you're trying to shut down.

Comment: true, but this answer should be amended to indicate "dealing with forms", not the more general "dealing with singleton objects". As far as I know, in VB6, this behavior is for forms only. It was intended to simplify things for new programmers, but did tend to confuse the issue a lot. Generally, I've also just avoided it in favor of always instantiating forms that I needed. Just tried in .net and you can still reference the form type directly to show it. I'd still say away from that syntax though...

Comment: @drventure: the singleton nature of forms is the expected behavior for any experienced VB6 developer.  There is no reason to avoid it if your form should have singleton semantics in your application.  The fact is, if you want to learn VB6 you have to understand this stuff in detail, and once you do, it's not a big deal.

Comment: It isn't a singleton at all, but a default global instance named the same as the (Form) class.  You can do the same thing with a VB6 Class though it requires editing the .CLS file outside the IDE.  In both cases you can create as many separate instances of the classes as you want, thus they aren't singletons.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: @Bob Riemersma - true, sorry for using the wrong word.  I've updated my answer to clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a special functionality in VB6 and earlier. I normally tried to avoid doing it, since I saw it more as a source of confusion rather than a help.

The following comment *In Visual Basic 6.0 and earlier versions, a special default instance of each form is automatically created for you, and allows you to use the form's name to access this instance.* is taken from this MSDN page: [Working with Multiple Forms in Visual Basic .NET: Upgrading to .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289529%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)