# Using Printer.Print in VB6

Tags: vb6

I come from a Java and .NET background.

In VB6 it appears that you do not always have to create an instance of a class when using it.  For example, when using the Printer class you can simply say Printer.print instead of having to create an instance first i.e. Dim printer As New Printer and then running printer.Print.  I know that Printer is a system object in VB6, but why don't you have to create an instance?

Answer (score 5):

Visual Basic traditionally had a large number of pre-defined identifiers that are directly recognized by the compiler.  The Printer object is one of those.  Under the hood, this is implemented with the [[appobject] attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366726.aspx) but that's carefully hidden in the language.  The runtime creates an instance of the COM coclass automatically, much like the As New syntax.  The DAO DBEngine object would be an example of one that isn't predefined in the language parser.

This is over and done with in VB.NET, a truly object oriented language with a large class library, much like Java.  There is no Printer object anymore, you're supposed to use the PrintDocument class.  The Printer object is still supported for legacy code, available in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.Compatibility.VB6 namespace.  It however requires the *New* keyword to create an instance of it.

Be careful investing a lot of time and energy in VB6, it is in all respects a badly outdated language.

Answer (score 0):

VB6 isn't an object oriented language in the same way as you would expect if you are used to newer languages. VB6 will do implicit instantiation and you can treat certain things as if it were static. For example, you can declare a variable of a form, but you don't have to. You can directly call a form and manipulate it without declaring it. In the case of the printer, it can't be explicitly declared and instantiated, but VB6 already has one available.

Comment: Thanks.  Say I create a new class called Employee and had a method called AddEmployee.  I would have to create an instance of Employee (I believe) i.e. I could not simply run Employee.AddEmployee (as if AddEmployee was a static method?

Comment: You can't treat "almost everything" as static. Forms are a special case, where the runtime provides an automatic instance of the form. It does not apply for other objects. So it would not apply for an Employee class that you create. As for the Printer, this is a singleton provided by the runtime.

Comment: Part of what's going on is that some syntax is recognized and handled differently. Print is one special case, not a method at all but a pseudo-method. You won't find it documented as a method, or visible in the Object Browser, or listed in Intellisense, nor can it be used with a With block. It has "parameter" syntax unlike a normal parameter list, etc. Yes, the compiler imposes this veneer on top of its very true object orientation, and objects can have "As New" instationation semantics, and Forms (and even Classes can) have a predeclared "As New" global instance.

Comment: You cannot instantiate `Printer` i.e. `Set o = New Printer` will not compile. `Set o = Printer` is shortcut for `Set o = VB.Global.Printer`. In `Printer.NewPage` the `Printer` is a property, not exactly "singleton", just the current device in `Printers` collection. Using `Print` operator on an object expects a certain (undocumented) interface (e.g. IVbPrintProvider) to be implemented by the object.

Comment: Changed my verbiage on "almost anything" and the printer. I actually had opened VS and tried making a declaration before and that was OK, but it doesn't work at compile time. Now @w0051977's comment, if you are creating classes, you should instantiate and not treat them as static. Trying to use VB6 in the most object oriented way possible will help with the code migration that will almost certainly need done in the future.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you explain what the difference is declaring an instance like this: dim Employee1 As New Employee and like this: Dim Employee1 As Employee Set Employee1 = New Employee

Comment: @w0051977 In the first case, `Employee1` will be auto-instantiated every time it is accessed and is `Nothing` at the moment of access. In the second case, it will not; when it goes to `Nothing`, it will stay `Nothing` until explicitly set again.

Comment: Read more about forms and also As New on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118314/does-vb6-allow-referencing-form-instance-as-a-singleton-just-by-naming-its-data